# How to filter a pivoted query to bring the records that has at least one count in a specific date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

Now, I have a pivoted query that will bring a set of events that took place on all the towns registered in a table and a date range.

This is my query:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #tempDates
(
    [FechaSt] Datetime
);

;WITH cte1 (S) AS (
SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) n (S)
),
cte2 (S) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte1 AS cte1 CROSS JOIN cte1 AS cte2),
cte3 (S) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte1 AS cte1 CROSS JOIN cte2 AS cte2)

INSERT INTO #tempDates

SELECT 
    [Result] AS [Fecha]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT CAST([Result] AS DATE) [Result] FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    TOP (DATEDIFF(day, @f1, @f2) + 1)
                    [Result] = DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY S) - 1, @f1)
                FROM cte3
            ) AS res
    ) AS [listaFechas];


select @cols = 
    STUFF
        (
            (
                SELECT 
                    DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(10), d.FechaSt, 120)) 
                FROM #tempDates d
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,''
        )

SET @query =
'
    SELECT
        IdMunicipio,
        Ciudad,
        Region,
        Base,
        ' + @cols + '
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT
                [Jc].[ID],
                [Jc].[IdMunicipio],
                [Wc].[Ciudad],
                [Wr].[Region],
                IIF
                (
                    [Mk].[EsBase] = 1,
                    ''<i class="fas fa-star fa-fw textoAmarilloSm"></i>'',
                    ''''
                ) AS [Base],
                CAST([Jc].[Fecha] AS date) AS [FechaJc]
            FROM [dbo].[Jornadas_Cronograma] [Jc]
            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[L_MunicipiosCapacitacion] [Mk]
                ON [Jc].[IdMunicipio] = [Mk].[ID]
            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[L_RegionesMundo] [Wr]
                ON [Mk].[RegionId] = [Wr].[RegionID] 
            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[L_CiudadesMundo] [Wc]
                ON [Mk].[CiudadId] = [Wc].[CityID] 
        ) X
        PIVOT
        (
            COUNT([ID])
            FOR [FechaJc] IN (' + @cols + ')
        ) pvt
    ORDER BY Ciudad ASC
'

execute(@query);
```

So, according to the specified date range (@f1 and @f2), I'm creating a temp table that stores all the dates within that range, to stuff that data afterwards to achive the pivot.

This is a sample of the data returned:

```
IdMunicipio | Ciudad | ... | 2022-10-02 | 2022-10-03 | 2022-10-04
1           | Bogotá | ... |      0     |      1     |     3 
2           | Cali   | ... |      0     |      12    |     3 
3           | Medell.| ... |      0     |      0     |     0 
4           | Buga   | ... |      0     |      10    |     0 
5           | Chía   | ... |      0     |      0     |     0 
6           | Cota   | ... |      0     |      0     |     0 
7           | Cajicá | ... |      0     |      0     |     2
```

What I need is to filter this query, so that it will only bring the towns that had at least 1 event within the date range, for this example it will be:

```
IdMunicipio | Ciudad | ... | 2022-10-02 | 2022-10-03 | 2022-10-04
1           | Bogotá | ... |      0     |      1     |     3 
2           | Cali   | ... |      0     |      12    |     3 
4           | Buga   | ... |      0     |      10    |     0 
7           | Cajicá | ... |      0     |      0     |     2
```

What I have tryed:

```
DROP TABLE #tempDates

DECLARE @f1 datetime = '2022-10-02';
DECLARE @f2 datetime = '2022-10-08';

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #tempDates
(
    [FechaSt] Datetime
);

;WITH cte1 (S) AS (
SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) n (S)
),
cte2 (S) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte1 AS cte1 CROSS JOIN cte1 AS cte2),
cte3 (S) AS (SELECT 1 FROM cte1 AS cte1 CROSS JOIN cte2 AS cte2)

INSERT INTO #tempDates

SELECT 
    [Result] AS [Fecha]
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            DISTINCT CAST([Result] AS DATE) [Result] FROM
            (
                SELECT 
                    TOP (DATEDIFF(day, @f1, @f2) + 1)
                    [Result] = DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY S) - 1, @f1)
                FROM cte3
            ) AS res
    ) AS [listaFechas];


select @cols = 
    STUFF
        (
            (
                SELECT 
                    DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(convert(CHAR(10), d.FechaSt, 120)) 
                FROM #tempDates d
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,''
        )

SET @query =
'
    SELECT
        IdMunicipio,
        Ciudad,
        Region,
        Base,
        ' + @cols + '
    FROM 
        (
            SELECT
                [Jc].[ID],
                [Jc].[IdMunicipio],
                [Wc].[Ciudad],
                [Wr].[Region],
                IIF
                (
                    [Mk].[EsBase] = 1,
                    ''<i class="fas fa-star fa-fw textoAmarilloSm"></i>'',
                    ''''
                ) AS [Base],
                CAST([Jc].[Fecha] AS date) AS [FechaJc]
            FROM [dbo].[Jornadas_Cronograma] [Jc]
            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[L_MunicipiosCapacitacion] [Mk]
                ON [Jc].[IdMunicipio] = [Mk].[ID]
            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[L_RegionesMundo] [Wr]
                ON [Mk].[RegionId] = [Wr].[RegionID] 
            INNER JOIN
                [dbo].[L_CiudadesMundo] [Wc]
                ON [Mk].[CiudadId] = [Wc].[CityID] 
            WHERE
                (
                    (
                        SELECT
                            COUNT(*)
                        FROM [dbo].[Jornadas_Cronograma] [Jb]
                        WHERE
                            (CAST([Jb].[Fecha] as date) BETWEEN ' + CAST(@f1 as date) + ' AND ' + CAST(@f2 as date) + ') 
                    )
                ) > 0;
        ) X
        PIVOT
        (
            COUNT([ID])
            FOR [FechaJc] IN (' + @cols + ')
        ) pvt
    
    ORDER BY Ciudad ASC
'

execute(@query);
```

But this will break into an error:

```
Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 92
The data types nvarchar(max) and date are incompatible in the add operator.
```

This is breaking in the line where I declare the WHERE Clause:

```
(CAST([Jb].[Fecha] as date) BETWEEN ' + CAST(@f1 as date) + ' AND ' + CAST(@f2 as date) + ')
```

I've thinked that maybe if a somehow SUM the results for the dates columns, I will be able to filter where that sum is > 0, but I'm not being able to solve the syntax.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data before it was pivoted?

Comment: I second @DannySlor, what does your raw data look like before the pivot?